# App not retrieving data from firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I cant seem to retrieve any information from my firebase database. I created a table with both author and title available.

[image: database screenshot]

This is the code i ran in my ios app, but the app just keeps crashing.

```
// Get a reference to our posts
Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl: @"**********"];

[ref observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    NSLog(@"%@", snapshot.value[@"author"]);
    NSLog(@"%@", snapshot.value[@"title"]);
}];

}
```

I cant tell whats going wrong, any help with this i will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: check if your firebase url proper

Comment: FEventTypeChildAdded is perfectly legitimate - it will iterate over each child node loading the children in one at a time. I tested it and this his code works correctly.  Perhaps your firebase url is not right, or you have rules in place preventing the data from being read? What line is it crashing on?

Comment: Let me add that it works perfectly assuming that this is not the root ref. If it is, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change event type to

```
[ref observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
     NSLog(@"%@", snapshot.value[@"author"]);
      NSLog(@"%@", snapshot.value[@"title"]);
 }];
```

Answer (score 1):

You would generally not store data like that right under your root node - it would generally be a child node(s) stored under the root node, like this:

```
sizzling-inferno-255
  book_node_0
    author: test_author
    title: test title
  book_node_1
    author: another author
    title: another title title


Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl: @"sizzling-inferno-255"];

[ref observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    NSLog(@"%@", snapshot.value[@"author"]);
    NSLog(@"%@", snapshot.value[@"title"]);
}];
```

will iterate over each book node and return a snapshot of that node. So the first time a snapshot is returned, it will be

```
  book_node_0
    author: test_author
    title: test title
```

and the second time a snapshot is returned will be

```
  book_node_1
    author: another author
    title: another title title
```

the book_node keys are generated with childByAutoId.

ChildAdded reads in each child node one at a time as a snapshot.

Value reads in everything in the node; all child nodes, those children etc and can be a large amount of data. If the ref node contains children, like in this answer, all of the nodes are returned and they need to be iterated over to get the child data, so within the observe block...

```
for child in snapshot.children {
   NSLog(@"%@", child.value[@"author"]);
}
```

Edit - and to specifically answer the OP question, here's how you do it with the Firebase structure in the question:

```
self.myRootRef = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://**********"];
[ref observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) { 
    NSString *key = snapshot.key;
    NSString *value = snapshot.value;

    if ( [key isEqualToString:@"author"] ) {
        NSLog(@"author = %@", value);
    } else if ([snapshot.key isEqualToString:@"title"] ) {
        NSLog(@"title = %@", value);
    }
}];
```

Comment: when i use this my log shows;
2016-05-17 10:03:53.535 Weather[996:26330] 0
2016-05-17 10:03:53.645 Weather[996:26330] (null)
2016-05-17 10:03:54.161 Weather[996:26330] (null)
2016-05-17 10:03:54.162 Weather[996:26330] (null)
2016-05-17 10:03:54.162 Weather[996:26330] (null)

Comment: @vype The 'Weather' text in your comment is a little confusing as that's not part of the the code or Firebase structure in your initial question. So, that means your URL is pointing to the wrong Firebase. I duplicated your Firebase structure and ran the code in my answer it worked correctly.